# Capacitor push notifications for Ios are empty when clicking on the notification banner

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, capacitor

My app uses push notifications (Ionic Capacitor) and when I enter the app I use `getDeliveredNotifications()` to get all the notifications to display. This works great if the user clicks on our App icon but when the user clicks the notification banner I get an empty array back.

Its like the notifications get wiped before getDeliveredNotifications gets called. Any thoughts on what I might try to fix? I checked this on Android and it works as expected...